# jquery appending to a index location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to make an rtf style text box. my get selection works when i alert the selection. i am trying to make it append a  before and after the selection. but everything i try it just keeps appending to the end of the html.

my Html is pretty simple

```
<p id="textblock" contenteditable="true">
This is just a simple paragraph tag that is content editable. the plan is to make it responsive to RTF controls like bold, italics, and other options.     
</p>

<button id="boldButton">BOLD</button>
<button id="viewButton">ViewHtml</button>
<button id="selection">ViewSelection</button>
```

and my jquery is

```
$( "#boldButton" ).click(function() {
    Boldify();
});

$( "#viewButton" ).click(function() {
  alert( $("#textblock").html() );
});

$( "#selection" ).click(function() {
  alert( document.getSelection().toString());
});

function Boldify(){
    var startIndex = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
    var endIndex = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;

$("<strong>").appendTo("#textblock").index(window.getSelection());
$("</strong>").appendTo("#textblock").index(endIndex);
}
```

here is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3oaup7gn/ I feel like i am close. but i seem to be missing something.  i have tried to use static indexes and also getSelection() indexes but it's always doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to utilize execCommand() my friend, just add this to the Boldify() function.

```
document.execCommand('bold', false, true);
```

Read the whole API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand

Comment: well that was a lot easier than i thought. lol. thanks a bunch